# stackoverflow-cli, a *nix stackoverflow command line client

Tags: app

No Screenshot.

### About

This is a small libcurl-based C application for the command line. I started this simply to brush up on my C and Linux/POSIX skills. Plus, I am playing around with a netbook loaded with archlinux and I am trying to keep it text only. Yes, I am nuts.

I plan for it to be usable i along with other Unix utilities, like grep, awk, etc. So results can be manipulated further with other applications. And used too.

#### License

No cost at all. I will probably use the BSD License, or MIT's.

#### Download

https://github.com/ebobby/stackoverflow-cli

No binaries. Source code only. There is a simple Makefile, if it doesn't work for your setup feel free to change it and send patches my way. ;)

Current dependencies are libcurl, json-c and getops GNU extensions.

#### Platform

I have just compiled it and run it on archlinux. I see no reason why it wouldn't compile and run in other *nix as well. It also compiles in my Macbook Pro.

### Contact

http://ebobby.org

You'll find how to reach me there.

### Code

Its written in C.

Dependencies/libraries: libcurl, json-c.

**Update**
The little app now runs the search api method and parses the json correctly displaying formattef output. Go and try it! More methods coming soon.

Comment: Would you consider moving some of this into a shared library?

Comment: Sure, the functionality can be wrapped into a library and the actual app simply rely on it. Want to help with that? ;)

Comment: I'll see what I can do. I'll fork the code on GitHub.